# Strange linebreaks with microtype & LuaLaTex

Tags: xetex, luatex, microtype

I have a weird problem. If I compile with `LuaLaTex` and `microtype` some of my line breaks are messed upped, but I don't get any warnings. `XeLaTex` with/without `microtype` or `LuaLaTex` without `microtype` are creating the document just right.

**Example**(I didn't want to post the real text, so I replaced some words)

- **LuaLatex & microtype**
  [image]
- **LuaLatex**
  [image]
- **XeLatTex & microtype**
  [image]
- **XeLatTex**
  [image]

**Example code**

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,ngerman]{scrbook}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}



\newcommand{\cen}[1]{\rule{#1pt}{1ex}}

\begin{document}
    \cen{11.77} \cen{33.79} \cen{20.367} \cen{9.13} \cen{23.148} \cen{52.06} 
    \cen{38.49}-\cen{38.64}-\cen{74.26} \cen{35.59}. \cen{15.66} \cen{23.15} 
    \cen{63.03914} \cen{17.03821} \cen{8.25} \cen{24.02} \cen{28.02} \cen{18.00}
    \cen{27.9} \cen{18.8559} \cen{80.55} \cen{17.03} \cen{22.19566} \cen{27.07}
    \cen{25.44} \cen{47.17} \cen{11.617} \cen{23.72} \cen{13.7} \cen{16.425}
    \cen{66.9264} \cen{15.2643} \cen{38.7411} \cen{41.97136} \cen{17.52}
    Ein\-pla\-ti\-nen\-rech\-ner \emph{Rasp\-berry Pi} benötigt als \cen{88.81546}
    \cen{15.51} \cen{18.26} \cen{23.43} \cen{27.76} \cen{24.02} \cen{13.73}
    \cen{33.78} \cen{66.92} \cen{58.18}


\end{document}
```

**Question** Why do I get this strange behavior? Is there any way to avoid this when using `LuaLaTex` and `microtype` for a document?

Comment: This is the same luatex bug as in [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28733/7674) and [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/104447/7674).

Comment: thx! Somehow I missed these questions. Really annoying bug :-/ And more than [3 years old](http://tracker.luatex.org/view.php?id=487)...

Comment: Seems like a straight-forward dupe, so I've marked as such.