# LuaLateX: Problem with microtype \textls and center environment

Tags: luatex, microtype

I want to use `\textls` to reduce letterspacing for citing works/compositions. If I use it in the titlepage inside a `center` environment it gets a bit messy. As in other examples, it seems like the lines somehow are moved to the right. The command inside normal text seems to work fine.

I use **LuaLateX** to compile.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, top=25mm, left=20mm, right=20mm, bottom=30mm,
headsep=0mm, footskip=12mm}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont={Latin Modern Roman Caps}]{Latin Modern Roman}

\newcommand{\work}[1]{\textsc{\textls[-50]{#1}}}

\begin{document}

    \begin{center}
    \huge
        Immanuel Kants \work{Kritik der praktischen Vernunft},

        \work{Kritik der reinen Vernunft} und

        \work{Kritik der Urteilskraft}

    \end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Remove the brace before `\huge` and the one before `\end{center}`.

Comment: same problem without braces. it's not about vertical but horizontal spacing

Comment: OK, retracted the vote for closing. I seem to remember that it's a problem with negative letterspacing. But the good typographical practice is to *space out* small caps, not the contrary. And the result in your picture is really bad, IMO.

Comment: Not a solution to your issue, but just a small request: Please write `Kant's`, not `Kants'`.

Comment: @Mico my fault. It's a german title so it doesn't need an apostroph at all.

Comment: It seems a bug in `microtype` with LuaLaTeX (or a `luatex` bug); if I remove the call to `fontspec`, compiling with `pdflatex` or `lualatex` should be the same, but the problem still appears.

Comment: @egreg It's a `luatex` bug, namely the one with negative protrusion values (like [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/104483/7674) and [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28742/7674)), as letterspacing triggers negative protrusion in `microtype`. (And I agree the tight spacing looks awful.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the LetterSpace feature instead:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, top=25mm, left=20mm, right=20mm, bottom=30mm,
headsep=0mm, footskip=12mm}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont={Latin Modern Roman Caps},
             SmallCapsFeatures={LetterSpace=-6}]{Latin Modern Roman}

\newcommand{\work}[1]{\textsc{{#1}}}

\begin{document}

    \begin{center}
    \huge
        Immanuel Kant's \work{Kritik der praktischen Vernunft},

         \work{Kritik der reinen Vernunft} und

        \work{Kritik der Urteilskraft}

    \end{center}

\end{document}
```

You can also burry the text in a fbox with invisible rules:

```
\newcommand{\work}[1]{{\fboxsep=0pt\fboxrule=0pt\fbox{\textsc{\textls[-50]{#1}}}}}
```

It also works if you add word joiners

```
 \newcommand{\work}[1]{\textsc{^^^^2060\textls[-50]{#1}^^^^2060}}
```

but only if the text is on one line. If there is a line break centering will be lost again.

Comment: I use the code of your MWE. Is there a way to reduce the word spacing too? It's too large now.

Comment: I asked a new question for that problem:
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208855/lualatex-fontspec-wordspacing-and-letterspacing

Answer (score 2):

as a workaround use

```
    ~\work{Kritik der reinen Vernunft} und~
```

[image]