# LuaTeX: Line break problem with microtype + geometry (bindingoffset)

Tags: line-breaking, luatex, geometry, microtype

I have a problem with the combination LuaTeX + package `microtype` + option `bindingoffset` from the `geometry` package when typesetting the following example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[showframe, inner=25mm, outer=25mm, bindingoffset=12mm]{geometry}
%\usepackage[showframe, inner=37mm, outer=37mm, bindingoffset=0mm]{geometry}

\usepackage[final]{microtype}

\begin{document}

Functions. According to 1, the free rotator's points are selected in two anyhow 
selected \emph{resulting} point 4 and any \emph{not-resultant} sept 2 which 
belongs to the rest of the system.

\end{document}
```

The first line does not break correctly, so a part of the text is written outside the main text frame. This problem only occurs if `bindingoffset` is set AND `microtype` is used. It also only occurs with LuaTeX, pdfTeX compiles it correctly. Here are the results of the tests I made:

```
TeX       bindingoffset  microtype   result
----------------------------------------------
pdfTeX     0mm           yes         ok
pdfTeX    12mm           yes         ok
LuaTeX     0mm           yes         ok
LuaTeX    12mm           yes         WRONG!
pdfTeX     0mm           no          ok
pdfTeX    12mm           no          ok
LuaTeX     0mm           no          ok
LuaTeX    12mm           no          ok
```

I used the following software:

- `pdfTeX` 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014)
- `LuaTeX` beta-0.79.1 (TeX Live 2014) (rev 4971)
- package `geometry`: version: 5.6 (revision: 19716)
- package `microtype`: version: 2.5a (revision: 30755)

Is this a bug in `geometry`, `microtype` or LuaTeX?

Comment: This is the same `luatex` bug as in [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28742/7674) (solutions [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/104483/7674)). According to the luatex [tracker](http://tracker.luatex.org/view.php?id=487) this has been fixed in the experimental version.